# 3xx redirect with "no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error

Tags: django, vue.js, cors, axios, django-cors-headers

[Repository with the project](https://github.com/huntekah/MastersThesis/tree/frontend-development)

I am getting information about blocked access by CORS policy and none of the solutions I looked at seemed to be working.

[image: error message]

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/search' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

---

My server is hosted locally on localhost:8000 and frontend is on loacalhost:8080. I want to post text data in Vue with Axios in file: [store.js%43:56](https://github.com/huntekah/MastersThesis/blob/frontend-development/frontend/src/store/store.js)
:

```
   axios.post('http://localhost:8000/search', {
      queryText: 'TEST_TEXT'
   }).then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response)
   }).catch(function (response) {
      // handle error
      console.log(response)
   })
```

the backend is written in Django with Rest API. I followed [those instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework) but the response is still the same. The view responsible for the response is [here](https://github.com/huntekah/MastersThesis/blob/frontend-development/emacsGpt2Extension/searchbar/views.py) and settings were set up [here](https://github.com/huntekah/MastersThesis/blob/frontend-development/emacsGpt2Extension/gpt2_django/settings.py)

I do not want to:

- Disable web security in Chrome
- Use JSONP
- Use a third party site to re-route my requests

---

If anyone would like to run the project just install requirements.txt from main folder and follow README from main and frontend folders.

Comment: Enable CORS on django, this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker  its `301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)`
@Rajeev Radhakrishnan I believe I did enabled those.

Comment: Look at the URL in the Location response header in that 301 response, and use that URL as your request URL instead of `http://localhost:8000/search`. Maybe you juse need to add a trailing slash — `http://localhost:8000/search/`. Anyway, it sounds like the `http://localhost:8000/search` server hasn’t been configured to add headers to 3xx responses. The configuration you’ve done so far is probably only adding the headers to 2xx responses.

Comment: I'll check it out back at home, may I ask you to add it as an official answer? after checking files I feel that trailing slash might have been the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable CORS settings in Django look at [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers).

Also if you are doing session based authentication, you might have to add some extra settings in your headers. I struggled with Angular2 a while back but I think if you face this issue [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381265/django-session-authentication-with-angular-2) will be relevant for you.